# Disable touch in bing map after map is initialized

Tags: bing-maps

How to disable mobile touch event after the bing map is initialized?

We can disable before initializing by below code, using MapOptions object. However I'm looking after the Bing Map is initialized.

```
// Set the map and view options, setting the map style to Road and
// removing the user's ability to change the map style
var mapOptions = {credentials:"Bing Maps Key",
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                  disableTouchInput : true,
};

// Initialize the map
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try attaching and de-attaching to click event.

Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click',attachClickEventhandler);

Then

Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(attachClickEventhandler);

Comment: Looks like you can't set that options once the map is loaded. Just curious, why do you need it to only be disabled after it is loaded?

Comment: @Bryant, I'm working on a responsive webpage. On desktop the tocuh should be allowed while on mobile it should be disable. The real problem is when some mobile with higher screen size shows desktop layout in landscape mode, so in this case the touch should be enabled. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the MapOptions do work when passed into the setOptions method of the map. For instance try this: map.setOptions({disableTouchInput: true});

Note that I've only tested this in IE. If you simply want to disable panning and zooming you can do this in a number of different ways. The first is to use map options, the other is to use the viewchange event, store the original map position and keep setting the map to the same view to lock it.

Comment: this is awesome. It's working, thanks a lot. I don't know why Bings Maps API document doesn't mention about this. Anyway thanks a lot!!!

Comment: At one point this didn't work. I think the development team added support for it but it never got communicated to the documentation team. I'll let them know so they can update it.

Comment: Looks like it actually is in the documentation for the Map Options. The ones (like show logo which I was using below) that can't be set all say "This property can only be set when using the Map constructor.", the ones that can be set omit this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't set most of the MapOptions once the map is created you can only do this by swapping out your map for a new map with the options you want. This is a very basic example, but here is an example that shows and hides the bing logo which is one of the settings that you can't change with setOptions.

```
function switchMapOptions(active, inactive) {

    try {
        var newMap = new MM.Map($(inactive)[0], options);

        for (var i = 0; i < map.entities.getLength(); i++) {
            var loc = map.entities.get(i).getLocation();
            newMap.entities.push(new MM.Pushpin(loc));
        }

        newMap.setView({center: map.getCenter(), zoom: map.getZoom(), animate: false});

        map.dispose();
        map = newMap;
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Full code at Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bryantlikes/zhH5g/4/